# PyMongo / MongoDB | How to delete a piece of data under a specific id

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to delete a piece of data under a id if you don't know what I mean just yet, I will explain in detail, I've seen tons of other documents on `remove` or `delete` but most of them contain deleting the id and all it's data completely, or it just mentions a bulk delete; basically anything that falls under a category is deleted affecting other documents.

Say we have collection `peoples`

```
{"_id": 1, "cool": 1}
{"_id": 2, "cool": 1}
{"_id": 3, "cool": 2}
{"_id": 4, "cool": 1}
{"_id": 5, "cool": 3}
#dont judge my sense of randomness
```

Now if I have a requirement in which if `cool` is equal to 4, then delete cool, if this was True then the file would look something like this;

Added +1 cool to every file

```
{"_id": 1, "cool": 2}
{"_id": 2, "cool": 2}
{"_id": 3, "cool": 3}
{"_id": 4, "cool": 2}
{"_id": 5}
```

As you can see every `id` with the data `cool` has been increased by 1, and since we made the requirement of if cool is equal to 4, then we should delete the data `cool` under `id : 5` (not the file + id completely!!!).

So my question is; how exactly would I do this, specify a certain id and then delete a certain piece of data under that id without affecting other files nor deleting the file and the id itself?

Thank you for reading and your time! :)))

Answer (score 1):

So first you'd need to get the `_id` of the document.
If you don't know how to find this, you can make a variable for all of the documents in the collection and iterate through it.

```
all_documents = collection.find({})
for document in all_documents:
    if document['cool'] == 4:
        collection.update({"_id": document["_id"]},{ $unset: {"cool": ""}})
```

Essentially, what you were asking for is this line:

```
collection.update({"_id": document["_id"]},{ $unset: {"cool": ""}})
```

You can read about it [here](https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb/mongodb-field-update-operator-$unset.php)